# Web scraping SEC filings

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on web scraping 10Q documents from SEC edgar.

This is the url link: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1652044/000165204419000032/goog10-qq32019.htm

If we inspect it you can find [image]

I need to extract 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway without using id. Below is a code snippet to extract text using id tag. However I need to se name tag.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()
page = session.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1652044/000165204419000032/goog10-qq32019.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find(id="d92517213e644-wk-Fact-0B11263160365DBABCF89969352EE602")
print(content.text)
```

Instead of id tag, I would like to use name tag. However I am not able to extract information sing name tag. Please help.

see the html information :

[image]

How to use name tag instead of id tag to extract the contents.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find elements based on attribute values like this

```
soup.find('html_tag',{"attribute":"value"})
```

So in your case, `name` attribute exists on `ix:nonnumeric` tag

```
content = soup.find('ix:nonnumeric',{"name":"dei:EntityAddressAddressLine1"})
```